# How to put lots of seconds between a command block without using redstone repeater?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What I want to do is put a command block down and do a command every 1 minute! How do I do this without redstone repeaters? I am doing this for a server!

Comment: Can the build not use redstone repeaters at all, or do you just not want an answer which is a chain of them?

Comment: Why aren't you allowed redstone repeaters? Is it a space issue or do you just not like them?

Comment: What you wanna do with this time between commands? A circle circuit that continues forever or a game countdown ?or something like that. I need to know how to explain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay or slowly loop commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/363578/how-to-delay-or-slowly-loop-commands)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve your goal just by using command blocks. Using a repeating command block, you can increment the score of a dummy player by 1, like so: (note you need to create the objective in the scoreboard beforehand.

```
/scoreboard players add count dummy_objective 1
```

Knowing that this command will happen 20 times/s by default, we can figure that a minute has occurred when the score reaches `20 times/s * 60 s/min = 1200`. Using a second repeating command block, you can use the following command to detect when the score reaches 1200:

```
/scoreboard players test count dummy_objective 1200
```

In conditional chain command blocks following the above command, you will need to set the score back to 0, then execute the commands that you want:

```
/scoreboard players set count dummy_objective 0
... <your commands>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some types of redstone timers that do not require repeaters.  The first one that comes to mind is a minecart timer.  I don't know the math off the top of my head, but the basic mechanism is that you have a minecart on a circular track, with enough powered rails to keep it at full speed, and one detector rail.  Make the track long enough that it takes one minute for the minecart to hit the detector rail.  Another, slightly more space efficient alternative is to make the cart travel the track (factor of 60) seconds, then have ((complimenting factor of 60) - 1) 1-bit memory cells which get activated one-by-one on each activation, resetting on the next signal once all of them are turned on.  For example, if the minecart travels the track in 15 seconds, turn one memory cell on on each iteration then send a signal to your command block on the 4th activation.  The main advantage to minecart timers is that they are precise even through server lag, with the downside being that you have to ensure nothing gets in the way of the minecart.

Another slightly silly alternative is to set your day/night cycle to occur every minute, and use a daylight detector connected to a dual edge detector (e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/plv3C.jpg).  Or just set it to do a complete cycle from day to night and back every minute.

Answer (score -1):

You can if you use a Timer Setup with scoreboard with a combination of /scoreboard players test.

Comment: Would you like to explain how the OP would go about doing this? The best answers on Arqade don't just tell, they *show* how to fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a slow clock quite easily with a minecart and cobwebs. Make a track that runs uphill and then falls onto cobwebs. For every cobweb you place, the minecart will take 30 more seconds to fall, so in your case, you'd need 2 cobwebs. Then, at the bottom, put powered rails and 1 detector rail to send out a signal, then connect that track to the one running uphill to make a loop.

Answer (score -2):

First of all judging from your question I think that you're trying to ask us all `"Is it possible to add delay to command blocks without repeaters?"`

It isin't possible to do sowith command blocks, not even with repeating command blocks, as they execute thier command every game tick `(20 times/s by default)`

So unfortunately you're **not** able to add any delay to command blocks without using any repeaters.

Comment: This is actually not true. By having a counting scoreboard command and conditional chain command blocks, you can cause commands to execute only after a certain number of game ticks.